# Thymeleaf exception only with JUnit test and not in the app

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using spring boot, spring security and thymeleaf for a web app. The problem is all is working fine when I test manually, but when I'm executing tests, I have an error :

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authentication.principal.username == transaction.buddySender.email" (template: "transfer" - line 101, col 13)
```

Here is my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Transfer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/transfer.css" th:href="@{/css/transfer.css}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo">Pay My Buddy</div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Welcome, <span sec:authentication="principal.firstName"></span>
                        <span sec:authentication="principal.lastName"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Remaining balance :
                        <span th:object="${sold}" th:text="${sold}"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a th:href="@{/}" class="active">Transfer</a></li>
                    <li><a th:href="@{profile.html}">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
                        <input class="input-logoff" type="submit" value="Log off" />
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="breadcrumb">
                <a href="#" class="blue-text">Home</a>
                <span class="blue-text">/</span>
                <a href="#">Transfer</a>
            </div>

            <div class="content-block">
                <div th:if="${param.addFriendError}">
                    <p class="text-danger">Already added or mail doesn't exist</p>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${param.errorTransaction}">
                    <p class="text-danger">Must select friend or put description and amount need to be >= 1</p>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${param.errorNotEnoughMoney}">
                    <p class="text-danger">You don't have enough money</p>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${param.friendAdded}">
                    <p class="text-success">Friend added successfuly</p>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${param.successfullTransaction}">
                    <p class="text-success">Transaction completed</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-container">
                    <p>Send Money</p>
                    <a href="#myModal"><button class="blue-button">Add Connection</button></a>
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <form method="post" th:action="@{/addFriend}" th:object="${buddy}">
                                <a href="" class="closeModal">&times;</a>
                                <h3>Enter an email</h3>

                                <input type="text" th:value="${buddy.email}" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
                                <button id="addConnectionButtonModal" type="submit">Add Connection</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form class="form-container" th:action="@{/pay}" th:object="${friends}" method="post">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <select name="email" id="email">
                            <option>Select a Connection</option>
                            <option th:each="friend : ${friends}" th:value="${friend.email}" name="email" th:text="${friend.firstName + ' ' + friend.lastName}"></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <input type="text" th:field="${newTransaction.description}" th:value="${newTransaction.description}" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Add Description" class="input-style" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <input type="number" min="0" value="0" step="0.01" placeholder="0€" th:field="${newTransaction.amount}" th:value="${newTransaction.amount}" id="amount" name="amount" class="input-style" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <button class="green-button" type="submit">Pay</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="transactions-block">
                <h2>My Transactions</h2>
                <div class="table-container">
                    <table class="transaction-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Connections</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="transaction: ${transactions}">
                                <td th:if="${#authentication.principal.username == transaction.buddySender.email}" th:text="${transaction.buddyReciever.firstName + ' ' + transaction.buddyReciever.lastName}"></td>
                                <td th:if="${#authentication.principal.username == transaction.buddyReciever.email}" th:text="${transaction.buddySender.firstName + ' ' + transaction.buddySender.lastName}"></td>
                                <td th:if="${#authentication.principal.username == transaction.buddySender.email}" th:text="${transaction.description}"></td>
                                <td th:if="${#authentication.principal.username == transaction.buddyReciever.email}" th:text="${transaction.description}"></td>
                                <td th:if="${#authentication.principal.username == transaction.buddySender.email}" th:text="${'- '+ #numbers.formatDecimal(transaction.amount * 1.005, 2, 2, 'COMMA')}"></td>
                                <td th:if="${#authentication.principal.username == transaction.buddyReciever.email}" th:text="${'+ ' + transaction.amount}"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

My only test with this problem is "shouldReturnHomePage :

```
package com.PayMyBuddy;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import com.PayMyBuddy.model.Buddy;
import com.PayMyBuddy.service.BuddyService;

import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
public class BuddyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private BuddyService buddyService;

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("jeandupont@mail.fr")
    public void shouldReturnHomePage() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("transfer"))
        .andExpect(model().attributeExists("buddy", "friends", "newTransaction", "transactions"))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("sold", 50.0));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void shouldReturnLoginPageHomeView() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("login"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "jeandupont@mail.fr")
    public void shouldReturnProfilePage() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/profile.html")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("profile.html"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void shouldReturnLoginPageProfileView() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/profile.html")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("login"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "jeandupont@mail.fr")
    public void addFriendInFriendListTest() throws Exception {
    Buddy jeandupont = buddyService.getBuddyByEmail("jeandupont@mail.fr");
    int numberOfFriends = jeandupont.getFriends().size();

    mockMvc.perform(post("/addFriend").param("email", "gilbertlarousse@mail.fr").with(csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()).andExpect(view().name("redirect:/?friendAdded"));

    assertEquals(jeandupont.getFriends().size(), numberOfFriends + 1);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "jeandupont@mail.fr")
    public void addFriendInFriendListWithUnknownUserTest() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/addFriend").param("email", "unknownUser@mail.fr").with(csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()).andExpect(view().name("redirect:/?addFriendError"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "jeandupont@mail.fr")
    public void addFriendWhoIsAlreadyFriendInFriendListTest() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/addFriend").param("email", "michelmartin@mail.fr").with(csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()).andExpect(view().name("redirect:/?addFriendError"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "jeandupont@mail.fr")
    public void addNullFriendInFriendListTest() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/addFriend").with(csrf())).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
        .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/?addFriendError"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void addFriendInUnknownUserFriendListTest() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/addFriend").param("email", "gilbertlarousse@mail.fr").with(csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()).andExpect(view().name("redirect:/?addFriendError"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void addNullFriendInUnknownUserFriendListTest() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/addFriend").with(csrf())).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
        .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/?addFriendError"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void addUnknownFriendInUnknownUserFriendListTest() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/addFriend").param("email", "unknownUser@mail.fr").with(csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()).andExpect(view().name("redirect:/?addFriendError"));
    }

}
```

When I log in into my app, all is working fine, I see the table's cells like I want to see them, it displays all good but the test just fail.
I just searched 3 hours on different forums any solution, but I didn't find a good solution. I tried to config a WebMvcConfig by adding the spring dialect but I saw that with SpringSecurity 5 and 6 it isn't needed. I still tried but when I launch my application with this config, I can't have access to the html file. It just displays the String that have the name of my HTML file in resources/templates.

Thank you and sorry for my english

I tried to add webMvcConfig, but didn't work fine

Comment: Please add your full test class and not only the test method. The test setup is on the class and in before methods. That is now completely missing from the question.

Comment: I edited my test class to add all the code

Comment: Also include the fullstacktrace instead of only the message. That should have some clues on why this is failing.

Comment: I see in the stacktrace that email is null. In my test it can't found email. I can't put the full stacktrace because it tells me there is too much characters

Comment: Well I doubt it is the email field, as that would just compare something to `null`. It would make more sense if the intermediate object would be `null` which would mean your test setup (the data needed) isn't there.

Comment: I don't know how to setup my test to "inject" user's email. When I print the email, it isn't null but my test doesn't seem to take it for the thymeleaf template

Comment: We really need the additional information, as stated I doubt the email is null but rather the intermediate elements in the `transaction.buddySender.email`, So either the `transaction` or the `buddySender`, resulting in `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I understand my mistake. I'm using a mySQL database for my app, and the database for test and my app are different. I just forgot to modified my test database...... Sorry